Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON. please guide me
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
I am trying to fetch some images data from an api. There are about 30 image urls in the api. I have atteched the code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BsArrowLeftCircleFill, BsArrowRightCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";

export default function ImageSlider({ url, limit }) {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  async function ImageFetching(url) {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const response = await data.json();
    setImages(response);
    console.log(images);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ImageFetching();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div>
      <BsArrowLeftCircleFill />
      {/* {images} */}
      <BsArrowRightCircleFill />
    </div>
  );
}



your server is sending a HTML page where your client expects JSON - perhaps use await data.text() instead
